# Why does Donald Trump continue the fight against the mass media?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, media

After reading [this article](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/01/21/us/politics/trump-white-house-briefing-inauguration-crowd-size.html), I wondered why is Donald Trump fighting the media? Isn't this a war that he cannot win?

- **media's force** - informally, the media is considered the [fourth power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_Estate) in a state
- **free speech** is one the most important values in the Western societies
- **technology** - current technology allows news reporting much more easier. Several decades ago most of the news was in printed form, so disrupting of news spreading was relatively easy (disrupt the printing or the distribution). Nowadays, virtually anyone with a smartphone can become an impromptu reporter.

**Question: what is the point of him threatening journalists and thus fighting with a part of the mass media?**

This behavior can be explained during the campaign, but what is the point after winning the elections?

Comment: Comments deleted. Please remember that comments on questions are for asking for clarification and providing constructive criticism to the question. They are not for stating your personal opinions about the subject of the question. They aren't for answering the question either. If you would like to answer, please write a proper answer which adheres to our quality standards.

Comment: Its too current.  I think in a few year (probably after he is out of office) we will be able to answer this.  But either he has an agenda that is not public, or its a neurosis, time will tell.

Comment: > Isn't this a war that he cannot win? many people said that about his fight with other republican candidates; then his fight with the republican party; then his fight with the democratic party; then his fight with the establishment of both parties; then his fight with hillary. Look who ends up in the white house? it doesn't pay to underestimate your enemy - hillary can teach you about that, :)

Comment: I would suggest people to look at why Berlusconi did the same things during its time.

Comment: MSM is the party -- Democrats are now just an arm of the MSM. MSM has always been biased going back to the '70s(at least), but they tried to hide it and give the appearance of un-biased reporting (by omitting stories or information, choosing of headlines, favoring weak Republicans during primaries (McCain, Boehner) - then savaging them during the campaigns; Starting in 2008 cycle this veil started to lift until the 2016 campaign -- when anyone who watches can see MSM is active enemy of republican party.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A way to answer this is to ask "what does each side (Donald Trump and the Media) win if one of them stops the fight ?"

I am taking CNN as a reference mass media. From a non-US point of view, the "Clinton News Network" nickname it was given is not really justified since CNN did not really take any side in the previous elections.

One of their critics towards him was his attitude towards facts. You may have seen, for instance, him denying things he said on tape ([Iraq war support](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sMgQAyZC-Vg)), or factual events ([Ukraine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=klZUiBJwVJY); [little story](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qSefxUxE_50) about the view from his apartment). If CNN does not debunk these, they may lose a lot of credibility, and hence viewers.

If Donald Trump stops saying things like "the media are among the most dishonest people on earth", some of his supporters may actually go back to listening the media, and little by little lose confidence in Mr Trump.

So he might as well keep trying to discredit the media, he has nothing to lose.

Comment: 0 sources and 3 votes? When biased (I'm not here to say whether they're right or wrong) answers toward one side have no sources, they are down-voted to oblivion. Shouldn't we have the same expectations of the other side?

Comment: @SirJony there really aren't sources for pure opinion (of which this question naturally produces...unless Trump comes here and answers it himself). That said, one merely needs to google to find plenty of examples of Trump not exactly adhering to reality in his statements. Citing examples might make this a better answer, but honestly, it's not a great question.

Comment: @SirJony I added sources. Note that it is hard to find a mass media that was never insulted by Trump.

Comment: > some of his supporters may actually go back to listening the media, and little by little lose confidence in Mr Trump. I think your basic assumption is that Trump supporters are too stupid to tells his lies. The payout for holding onto that kind of believe has not been great - just ask Hillary or Jeb.

Comment: Didn't take sides? CNN's parent company was one of Clinton's top donors, and there are many examples of CNN applying double standards almost entirely to Clinton's benefit, or giving air time to Clinton-friendly talking heads. And it doesn't make sense to consider any election other than 2016 in evaluating whether the term is justified.

Comment: Consider that much of Trump's base already distrusts the mainstream media (but not all media - they have their own less-known media sources).  Trump does not even need to be carrying out a clever strategy here - just repeating what his voting base believes.